# Limiting behavior of $L^2$-norm of error in divided-difference approximation of $f'$, where $f, f' \in L^2([0,\infty))$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $a < 0$, and let $f : (a, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. Suppose that the restrictions of $f$ and $f'$ to $[0,\infty)$ belong to $L^2([0,\infty))$. Do we then have, in general,
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\int_0^\infty\Bigg|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-f'(x)\Bigg|^2\,dx = 0?
$$
Obviously, there are many functions $f$ for which this equality holds.

A related question is the following. Suppose that the functions $f$ and $f'$ belong to $L^2([0,\infty), w(x)dx)$, where $w : [0, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$ is continuous and monotone-decreasing, and, for some $r > 1$,
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}x^rw(x) = 0.
$$
I mean by $L^2([0, \infty), w(x)dx)$ the space consisting of functions $g : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\int_0^\infty|g(x)|^2\,w(x)\,dx < \infty.
$$
 Do we then have, in general,
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\int_0^\infty\Bigg|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-f'(x)\Bigg|^2\,w(x)\,dx = 0?
$$

Answer (score 1):

For a locally integrable $g$ on $\mathbb R$ define

$$Mg(x) = \sup_{h>0}\frac{1}{2h}\int_{x-h}^{x+h} |g|.$$

This is the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function of $g.$ A well known result asserts there is a constant $C$ such that
$\|Mg\|_2 \le C\|g\|$ for all $g\in L^2.$

In our problem

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h} f'.$$

Thus

$$\left |\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right | \le \frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h} |f'| \le 2M(f')(x).$$

It follows that the integrand of interest is bounded above by $8(M(f')(x))^2 +2(f'(x))^2$ for every $x.$ But this function is in $L^1.$ Thus the dominated convergence theorem answers your first question in the affirmative.